# Is this exercise question well-posed? Dependence of marginal normals with correlation $\rho$

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, copula

An exercise question asks me to find the tail-dependence of $X$ and $Y$, where $\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y) = \rho$, and both $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal variables.

The tail-dependence is $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}P(X \ge \Phi^{-1}(x) \mid Y \ge \Phi^{-1}(x))$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function.

However, I wonder whether this question is ill-posed? The tail-dependence clearly depends on the joint distribution of $\Phi(X)$ and $\Phi(Y)$, i.e. their copula. However, I don't seem to have enough information to pin down that copula. It could be anything, could it not?

So, is this question answerable in its current form? If it is, please just explain why, but don't give the answer itself.

Comment: Well, the correlation is supposed to be a given value $\rho$, so it can't be anyting, but there are still many possibiulities.  What I would do is to try the question for different copulas, starting with a gauyssian copula, then try others ...

Comment: Yes, I know it can't be anything. That was a figure of speech. But as you say, there are many different possibilities, and I am not sure why it would help to try different ones. How does that make the question more answerable? It seems kind of arbitrary. Surely we are looking for a single, unique answer... unless the answer is the same across all possible copulas, but if so, how would one prove that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler, and exactly equivalent, to define the tail dependence as $$ \lim_{a\to+\infty} \Pr(X\ge a\mid Y\ge a) \text{ ?} $$

Comment: Have you somehow proved that for different copulas consistent with both the two marginals and the correlation you get different answers?

Comment: @Jako40: I don't know how you would prove, but why not make the exercise into an interesting one by investigating for different copulas?

Comment: You might find it interesting to prove that indeed the tail dependence *can* be anything provided $|\rho|\lt 1$ (within reason: the tail dependence either does not exist or is a probability, whence it will be in the interval $[0,1]$).